# Kafka Streams: Grouping by a key in Json log

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have kafka Streams application with an input topic `input` on which the following records come as json logs:

**JSON log:**

`{"CreationTime":"2018-02-12T12:32:31","UserId":"abc@gmail.com","Operation":"upload","Workload":"Drive"}`

I am building a stream from the topic:

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> source_user_activity = builder.stream("input");
```

Next I want to groupBy `"UserId"` and find count against each user.

```
final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();

final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> source_user_activity = builder.stream("input");

final KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = source_user_activity
        .flatMap((key, value) -> {
            List<KeyValue<String, String>> result = new LinkedList<>();
            JSONObject valueObject = new JSONObject(value);
            result.add(KeyValue.pair((valueObject.get("UserId").toString()), valueObject.toString()));
            return result;
        })
        .groupByKey()
        .count();

wordCounts.toStream().to("output",Produced.with(stringSerde, longSerde));
wordCounts.print();
```

Next I am consuming records from `output` topic using `console-consumer`. I am not seeing any text, its just some thing like this:

However `wordCounts.print()` shows this:

`[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000003]: abc@gmail.com, (1<-null)`

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Check out the examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Can you kindly look at the updated question?

Comment: No clear what your question is exactly? Is it about consuming from the output topic? How do you consume from the output topic?

Comment: I am using console-consumer to consume records. And I am seeing a strange character. Kindly see the above attached image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data of the value is encoded as `long` (you are using `LongSerde` for the value) and console consumer users `StringDeserializer` by default, and thus, it cannot correctly deserialize the value.

You need to specify `LongDeserializer` via a command line argument for the console consumer for the value.